# Stored procedure gives no results, truncate works, but inserts nothing

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, union, sql-insert, common-table-expression

Busy writing my first stored procedure in SQL, I hit an issue that I cannot solve myself.

The stored procedure has to truncate a table and insert new values in it. The truncate goes well, but the inserts don't. When I run the query outside the procedure It returns the expected results.

I start the procedure manually.

- The datatypes in the procedure match the datatypes in the target table
- Running the query outside the procedure returns the expected results

**This the code:**

```
Create Procedure Usp_Max_DateUpdated( 
        @TableName nvarchar (50)    
    ,   @Max_DateUpdated numeric(6,0)   
)
as
Begin

set nocount on;

truncate table Max_UPMJ;


With CTE_Fact_Account_Ledger as(
select 
cast(isnull(max([DateUpdated (GLUPMJ)]),0) as numeric(6,0)) as Max_DateUpdated,
'Fact_Account_Ledger' as TableName 
from DWH_Backroom.dbo.Fact_Account_Ledger
)

, CTE_Dim_Company as(
select 
cast(isnull(max([DateUpdated (CCUPMJ)]) ,0) as numeric(6,0)) as Max_DateUpdated, 
'Dim_Company' as TableName
from DWH_Backroom.dbo.Dim_Company
)

insert into Max_UPMJ (DateUpdated, TableName)
select 
Max_DateUpdated,
TableName 
From CTE_Fact_Account_Ledger CFAL
where Max_DateUpdated = @Max_DateUpdated and TableName = @TableName

union 

select 
Max_DateUpdated,
TableName
From CTE_Dim_Company
where Max_DateUpdated = @Max_DateUpdated and TableName = @TableName

End
```

**The expected result is:** (from query)

- DateUpdated 119183 , Tablename Fact_Account_Ledger
- DateUpdated 0, Tablename Dim_Company

**Result from procedure**
no rows

**Result from query*
2 rows affected

Edit: there are no error messages and the return value is 0

Comment: So what *does* happen when you run the SP? `@Max_DateUpdated` implies it's a date, so why is it declared as a`numeric`?

Comment: did you have any error.?

Comment: It is a Oracle dateformat from the database (Year, days in years), numeric is fine.

Comment: No error code is given back, only that the return value = 0, so should be fine :) thanks for the quick repsonses

Comment: *"It is a Oracle dateformat from the database (Year, days in years), numeric is fine."* It's not "fine" when you're having the `CAST` the value for your `WHERE`; making any indexes you did have useless. Data should be provided using a suitable data type; `numeric` is not a suitable datatype for date (and time) data, the date and time datatypes are.

Comment: Prove your query runs outside of the procedure. What values do you use in place of your parmeter when you test the logic this way? A trivial amount of additional debug code should provide sufficient information to help you debug your own code. As a start, add "select count(*), 'Fact_Account_Ledger' from <...>Fact_Account_Ledger" immediately before the union. Similarly you could add "select top 1 ..." for the other table. Lastly, your use of a tablename parameter is very odd given that your queries select from specific tables.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, I agree with you about providing data with a suitable data type. In this case `numeric` is the correct format ;) It is a bit too much to show the entire solution I inherited, but for now this makes sense, enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

1) By placing `(@TableName nvarchar (50),   @Max_DateUpdated numeric(6,0))` directly after the `create procedure` I called for variables that do not exist;

2) No parameters or variables seemed to be necessary in this procedure.

The following code works:

```
Create Procedure Usp_Max_DateUpdated

as
Begin

set nocount on;

truncate table Max_UPMJ;

With CTE_Fact_Account_Ledger as(
select 
        cast(isnull(max([DateUpdated (GLUPMJ)]),0) as numeric(6,0)) as Max_DateUpdated
    ,   'Fact_Account_Ledger' as TableName 
from DWH_Backroom.dbo.Fact_Account_Ledger
)

, CTE_Dim_Company as(
select 
        cast(isnull(max([DateUpdated (CCUPMJ)]) ,0) as numeric(6,0)) as Max_DateUpdated
    ,   'Dim_Company' as TableName
from DWH_Backroom.dbo.Dim_Company
)

insert into Max_UPMJ (DateUpdated, TableName)

select 
        Max_DateUpdated
    ,   TableName 
From CTE_Fact_Account_Ledger CFAL

union 

select 
        Max_DateUpdated
    ,   TableName
From CTE_Dim_Company
;
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure insert rows into Max_UPMJ. But not select this rows.
If you want see this rows, you should append the code `select * from Max_UPMJ`

Answer (score 0):

Try `@Max_DateUpdated DateTime`

I had this exact problem. Drove Me Crazy for a While. The problem is always the parameters. You don't see this problem when you run the query directly, because the way you declare variables there is different.

If you want to prove that your parameter data types in your stored procedure are problematic check if you are using the same datatypes as your 'identical' query that you say is working.

Also using SQL profiler you can see what parameter values are actually passed. Sometimes date formats can give you problems too.